# Powershell - Install an application

Tags: powershell

How would I run a program installer (in `C:\Downloads`) using a Powershell V1 script?

I do not have control over the Powershell version so please do not ask me to update to newer version.

If I do it manually, there will be a few options for me to choose before installing. I also have to specify the location for the application.

If I have to do it via scripts, how do I set which options to choose and specify the location?

I have searched the application support page and they do not have anything I need for the installation of the software via scripts.

I am not a very skilled person when it comes to scripting as I just started out months ago.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing the details of the installer. If the installer is an MSI file this should be a piece of cake. If it's just a regular executable it depends if a silent installer is supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)? It's a Windows package manager that allows you to install Windows applications using CLI.

To install Chrome for example:

```
choco install googlechrome
```

You can find all the available packages [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages).

Comment: Chocolatey requires Powershell V2 according to their own information.